# How to consistently standardize sparse feature matrix in scikit-learn?

Tags: scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I am using sklearn's `DictVectorizer` to construct a large, sparse feature matrix, which is fed to an `ElasticNet` model. Elastic net (and similar linear models) work best when predictors (columns in the feature matrix) are centered and scaled. The [recommended approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24101467/1541036) is to build a `Pipeline` that uses a `StandardScaler` prior to the regressor, however that doesn't work with sparse features, as stated in the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler).

I thought to use the `normalize=True` flag in `ElasticNet` which seems to support sparse data, however it's not clear whether the normalization is applied during prediction to the test data as well. Does anyone know if `normalize=True` applies for prediction as well? If not, is there a way to use the same standardization on the training and test set when dealing with sparse features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging through the sklearn code, it looks like when `fit_intercept=True` and `normalize=True`, the coefficients estimated on the normalized data are projected back to the original scale of the data. This is similar to the way `glmnet` in R handles standardization. The relevant code snippet is the method `_set_intercept` of `LinearModel`, see https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/base.py#L158. So predictions on unseen data use coefficients in the original scale, i.e., `normalize=True` is safe to use.